# WebView doesn't play video

Tags: android, video, webview

I have an Url,Actually this url shows ad so it may be an img,video.If we get video then onclick video should play.But it's not playing.I'm using Dell strek(2.2).So please suggest me how to solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the video player and URLs in the onCreate and do the actual playing by implementing onClickListener.

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    TabHost th;
    VideoView video;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create tabs using XML

        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        String path1 = "YOUR_URL";
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setAnchorView(video);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(video);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path1);
        video.setMediaController(mc);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                video.start();
            }

        });

    }
}
```

hope this will help you.